# The given input is date time format or what in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have variable of type string now i have to know the given input in variable is date.

i am using  if `(DateTime.TryParse(count,out dDate))` for that but it not work properly.

Here count is my string variable;

Comment: some times it returns false when in input date is comes. i think its a problem of format.

Comment: It needs to be in the format of the current culture or you can use the overload that accepts culture formatting information [DateTime.TryParse Method (String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e(v=vs.110).aspx)